# Finding the max/min value of a function with a given constraint

Tags: derivatives, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

I have a function $$f(x,y,z)=x^3+y^3+z^3$$ and it is subjected to the constraint $$g(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-25$$
I need to find the maximal and minimal values of this function (with this constraint) and this is what I have so far:
$$\nabla f=(3x^2, 3y^2, 3z^2), \nabla g=(2x,2y,2z)$$
$$x(3x-2\gamma)=0 => x=0, x=\frac {2\gamma} {3}$$
$$y(3y-2\gamma)=0 => y=0, y=\frac {2\gamma} {3}$$
$$z(3z-2\gamma)=0 => z=0, z=\frac {2\gamma} {3}$$
and now I am not sure how to proceed because I know I should use the constraint and do $x^2+y^2+z^2=25$ but I am not sure how to use it in this case as $x,y,z$ may be equal 0, there are so many possibilities.. please help.

Comment: You might look into Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: Note that $x,y,z$ can also be negative

Comment: Due to the cyclic property, it suffices to consider three cases:  $x=y=z$ are non-zero, exactly one of $x,y,z$ is zero, two are zeros. Then plug them into the constraint (equation of a sphere) and compute gamma. You can then evaluate $f(x,y,z)$ and decide, which one is maximal and which minimal. As @Henry pointed out, think of positive and negative values.

Comment: Combing your three equations $x=0,x=2\gamma/3$ etc. you'll get eight equations for $x$, $y$, and $z$.  In total you'll get twenty-four solutions for the system.  Let $w=\sqrt{25/2}$, these are: $(0,0,\pm5)$, $(0,\pm5,0)$, $(\pm5,0,0)$, $(0,\pm w,\pm w)$, $(\pm w,\pm w,0)$, $(\pm w, 0, \pm w)$, $(\pm\sqrt{25/3},\pm\sqrt{25/3},\pm\sqrt{25/3})$.